# AngularJS Protractor: Step-by-step progress logs

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, jasmine-spec-reporter

In the (now deprecated) angular scenario test runner, there was an option to create a runner.html page that would run the tests in an iFrame while reporting the progress, step-by-step, in the main page.

[image: Screenshot of scenario runner]

Is there any way to get a similar step-by-step log for protractor tests?  It does not need to be in an html page (console or log file would be fine).

Comment: jasmine-spec-reporter  doesn't suit your needs ?

Answer (score 5):

For that you can use the [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter) for protractor. You'll have a visual feedback of all your passing and non-passing tests :

[image]

Easy to configure and looks really good in the console.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since [v1.0.0-rc2](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-rc2) you can see failures in real time:

In your protractor config, add a `jasmineNodeOpts` object with `realtimeFailure` option to `true`:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'e2e/**/*.js'
  ],

  multiCapabilities: [
    {'browserName': 'firefox'},
    {'browserName': 'chrome'}
  ],

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000',

  onPrepare: function() {},

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    realtimeFailure: true
  }
};
```

The full list of jasmine options is here:  [minijasminenode](https://github.com/juliemr/minijasminenode/tree/jasmine1)

And the well detailed reference config file for protractor here: [referenceConf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2131c03c8cc6888307125ee331e1cecab5cbee27/docs/referenceConf.js)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a step in the right direction, but I was looking for something that reported each steap, even those that passed.  I'll add a screenshot so the question is more clear.